# MongoDB aggregate sorting before group

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm having trouble getting sorting correct with MongoDB. I basically want to sort the grouped results before they are grouped.

For example: I want to group results by handset, but each handset might have 100 deals. I want to sort these by handset cost and line rental before the results are grouped.

This is what I have so far:

```
array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$handset_numeric_id',
        'full_handset_name' => array('$push' => '$full_handset_name'),
        'deal_id' => array('$push' => '$deal_id'),
        'handset_url' => array('$push' => '$handset_url'),
        'deal_url' => array('$push' => '$deal_url'),
        'image_url' => array('$push' => '$image_url'),
        'phone_cost' => array('$push' => '$phone_cost'),
        'tariff_name' => array('$push' => '$tariff_name'),
        'minutes' => array('$push' => '$minutes'),
        'texts' => array('$push' => '$texts'),
        'data' => array('$push' => '$data'),
        'effective_monthly_cost' => array('$push' => '$effective_monthly_cost'),
        'network_numeric_id' => array('$push' => '$network_numeric_id'),
        'network_name' => array('$push' => '$network_name'),
        'manufacturer_name' => array('$push' => '$manufacturer_name'),
    ),
),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'phone_cost' => 1,
            'effective_monthly_cost' => 1
        )
    ),
);
```

What is the best way for me the get around this?

UPDATED:

This is result I'm getting:

```
Samsung Galaxy S III Mini amber Orange  0   47  The Works 47 (24m)  5000

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   38.67   The Works 47 (24m)  5000

Samsung Galaxy S III Mini black Orange  0   42.83   The Works 47 (24m)  5000

Samsung Galaxy S III amber  Orange  0   47  The Works 47 (24m)  500
```

As you can see above, MongoDB has picked the Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white with the £38.67 tariff, but this isn't the cheapest effective monthly cost.

If you look at the data below, you will see that the cheapest effective monthly cost is £27.21

```
Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   27.21   The Works 47 (24m)  5000

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   28.46   The Works 47 (24m)  5000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   29.29   The Works 47 (24m)  5000

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   31.38   The Works 52 (24m)  8000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   31.38   The Works 52 (24m)  8000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   32.21   The Works 47 (24m)  5000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   33.67   The Works 52 (24m)  8000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   34.5    The Works 52 (24m)  8000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   38.67   The Works 47 (24m)  5000    

Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 white    Orange  0   47  The Works 47 (24m)  5000
```

Sample of of the data from my input:

```
array (
  'deal_id' => '815300000000',
  'handset_numeric_id' => 305110,
  'handset_url' => 'samsung-galaxy-s4-active-grey',
  'deal_url' => 'samsung-galaxy-s4-active-grey?type=paym&deal=m056030510815300000000',
  'image_url' => 'samsung-galaxy-s4-active-grey',
  'handset_id' => 'galaxys4activegrey',
  'phone_cost' => 0,
  'tariff_numeric_id' => 814553,
  'tariff_id' => 'talktalk300-3000-1500-354441.24',
  'tariff_name' => '300 mins and 3000 texts with 1.5GB (24m)',
  'network_name' => 'TalkTalk',
  'network_numeric_id' => 1345,
  'term' => 24,
  'minutes' => 300,
  'texts' => 3000,
  'data' => 1500,
  'org_line_rental' => 35,
  'effective_monthly_cost' => 35,
  'total_cost_over_term' => 840,
  'gift_category' => 'Free Connection',
  'gift_category_numeric_id' => 2,
  'free_gift_id' => 0001,
  'free_gift_name' => 'FREE Sony PS3 Super Slim 500GB',
  'cashback' => 0,
  'free_lr' => 0,
  'half_lr' => 0,
  'included_cashback' => 0,
  'free_lr_number' => 0,
  'half_lr_number' => 0,
  'free_half_amount' => 0,
  'clearance_flag' => 0,
  'manufacturer_numeric_id' => 2,
  'manufacturer_name' => 'Samsung',
  'full_handset_name' => 'Samsung Galaxy S4 Active grey',
  'popularity' => 15534234202,
  'handset_colour' => 'grey',
  'tariff_type' => 'paym',
  'feature_ids' => '4,w,b,x,c,8,v,t,r,l,q,i,',
  'operating_system' => 'Android OS v4.2.2',
  'retailer_id' => 'talktalk',
  'retailer_name' => 'TalkTalk',
)
```

Comment: You seem to be "pushing" all of your results into arrays, and I would be almost certain that is not the result you really want. For one you are trying to sort on what is effectively an array, and you cannot do that. Perhaps show a small sample of data in your question and your expected result.

Comment: Hi, I've added in some example data

Comment: What I actually meant was a sample of the data from the input and not the output.

Comment: ok I've added an example of the input data

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you are effectively sorting after the grouping is done. If the phone or line cost varies for 1 handset, say handset A, then you should include the cost in your grouping key (_id). At the moment, you just creating for say handset A an array of phone costs and line rentals for handset A.

For what you want to do, the best way is to include the price and line rental into your grouping key. Replace your group _id key by the following.

```
$group => array( '_id' => array(handsetId => '$author', phone_cost => '$phone_cost', effective_monthly_cost=> '$effective_monthly_cost' ),
```

....

and then in the following step in the aggregation pipeline you can sort by the phonecost or line rental.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, using the above code example now gives me multiple handsets, when I only want to pick one handset. from this one handset that it picks, I want it to choose the cheapest effective cost per month.

Comment: Neil, I see what you mean. In this case, keep your original aggregation pipeline as above, but instead of doing the $push operation on the phone_cost and effective_monthly_cost, replace the it by the $min command. that should group your data by handset ID and set the fields to the minimum possible for that ID. your sorting part after should work fine then.